# rx.net merge reset stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

We have a running service which processes messages from system x to system y.
It basically looks as follows:

```cs
aSystem.Messages.Subscribe(message => 
{
   try
   {
      ProcessMessage(message);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      _logger.LogFatal(ex.Message);
   }
})
```

The problem is that we receive at least one message every second and our `LogFatal` message is configured to send an email. As a result, the mailbox exploded in a certain moment.

The code is "improved" by adding a custom Logging class which will hold the last timestamp. Based on that timestamp the message would log or not.

This looks cumbersome and I think this is the perfect scenario for `Rx.NET`. What we need is the following:

- 1) Log if the string changes
- 2) Log if a certain time passed

What I tried is the following:

```cs
var logSubject = new Subject<string>();
var logMessagesChangedStream = logSubject.DistinctUntilChanged(); // log on every message change
var logMessagesSampleStream = logSubject.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // log at least every 10 seconds

var subscription = logMessagesChangedStream.Merge(logMessagesSampleStream).Subscribe(result =>
{
    _logger.LogFatal(result);
});

aSystem.Messages.Subscribe(message => 
{
   try
   {
      ProcessMessage(message);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      logSubject.OnNext(ex.Message);
   }
})
```

It looks like it's working, but this will log the message twice, once for the `DistinctUntilChanged` and once for the `Sample`. So somehow I should reset the streams if one of them emitted a value. They work perfect independently, once merged they should listen to each other ;-)

Comment: Care to explain downvote? Something not clear?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Upvoted back up.

Comment: Do you want to log the last value every ten seconds (repeatedly)?

Comment: @Asti no, only if there is a new value. But max. once every ten seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the ambiguous operator `Amb` which races two sequences to see which wins first.

```
Observable.Amb(logMessagesChangedStream, logMessagesSampleStream)
```

The winning stream continues to propagate to the end - we don't want that. We're interested in starting the race again for the next value. Let's do that:

```
    Observable.Amb(logMessagesChangedStream, logMessagesSampleStream)
      .Take(1)
      .Repeat()
```

Now the last problem is that `DistinctUntilChanged` loses its state every time we restart the race, and its behavior is to push the very first value it gets immediately. Let's fix   that by turning it into a hot observable.

```
logSubject.DistinctUntilChanged().Publish();
```

Putting it all together:

```
var logSubject = new Subject<string>();
var logMessagesChangedStream = logSubject.DistinctUntilChanged().Publish(); // log on every message change
var logMessagesSampleStream = logSubject.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // log at least every 5 seconds    

var oneof =
        Observable
          .Amb(logMessagesChangedStream, logMessagesSampleStream)
          .Take(1)
          .Repeat(); 

   logMessagesChangedStream.Connect();
   oneof.Timestamp().Subscribe(c => Console.WriteLine(c));
```

Changed the 10 seconds to 5, [because](https://christinasessoms.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/30619964.jpg).

**Test**

```
    Action<string> onNext = logSubject.OnNext;

    onNext("a");
    onNext("b");
    Delay(1000, () => { onNext("c"); onNext("c"); onNext("c"); onNext("d"); });
    Delay(3000, () => { onNext("d"); onNext("e"); });
    Delay(6000, () => { onNext("e"); });
    Delay(10000, () => { onNext("e"); });
```

**Output**

```
a@1/30/2020 12:17:52 PM +00:00
b@1/30/2020 12:17:52 PM +00:00
c@1/30/2020 12:17:53 PM +00:00
d@1/30/2020 12:17:53 PM +00:00
e@1/30/2020 12:17:55 PM +00:00
e@1/30/2020 12:18:00 PM +00:00
e@1/30/2020 12:18:05 PM +00:00
```